# Importing private data into Google Colab notebook with R Kernel

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have private data that I would like to upload into a Google Colab notebook.  All of the solutions online which involve mounting a Google Drive assume that a Python kernel is being used.  How would I do this for an R notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your private data in S3.
Then, use s3fs to mount your s3 bucket to access it.
Here's a code in python.

https://gist.github.com/korakot/e28ea5269129b70f220fe5e8d065b446

You need to convert ! to R with system(...) instead.